# Book about a princess climbing a mountain to find a wizard

Tags: story-identification, books

When I was in middle school I read a book about a girl princess in a valley kingdom. There was magic and all that fun stuff. She was raised in the ways of the court, but her family died and she had to be a very young ruler. There was a scene where she climbed a mountain to find a wizard to help her with a problem. There was some romance, but ultimately she had to choose her nation over her love, which was really sad. She rode a giant wolf, if I remember clearly. And I'm fairly certain that there was either a mirror in the title or on the cover page. It was a series and very good.

Comment: Hello, Mackenzie! Around when did you read this? [This nice guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/102999) may help you with listing more details to bring up your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Something from [Elfquest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elfquest) perhaps?